# Difference between ffmpeg versions

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube-dl

I am using ffmpeg and ffprobe to do video/audio conversions when using youtube-dl in a GUI interface. The current ffmpeg version command line tool on windows is very large, over 100MB.
I want to downgrade it so the installer package won't be too large.

I want to know if there will be any obvious difference, if any, in converted files quality. By eyes and ears I can't spot any and I don't know how to use any tool that measures quality.

EDIT:

The ffmpeg version I want to downgrade to is the one that comes with [By Click Downloader](https://www.byclickdownloader.com/). The output when I request the version is below:

```
ffmpeg version N-70239-g111d79a Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      54. 19.100 / 54. 19.100
libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavformat    56. 23.105 / 56. 23.105
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 11.101 /  5. 11.101
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

That executable is only 28MB.

Edit2:

The video formats I want to use are mp4, webm, flv, 3gp, avi and audio formats are mp3, m4a, wav, aac, flac, opus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Difference between ffmpeg versions

Refer to [`Changelog`](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/Changelog). Note that `Changelog` is not comprehensive; it only lists notable features. FFmpeg development is very active so that means **a lot** is omitted from `Changelog`.

If you want to see **all** changes and updates (there are many) see the [git log](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git) and refer to each release tag.

It is never recommended to downgrade. You could miss out on thousands of updates and encounter old bugs that have already been fixed.

## Smaller ffmpeg

For Windows if you want a smaller executable then try:

- The *essentials* builds instead of *full* builds from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/).
- Compiling it yourself with help from [media-autobuild_suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite) and choosing only what you need.

Comment: I am trying media-autobuild_suite, based on the OP edit which states the formats I need what are options that I need to use with thee media-autobuild_suite?

Comment: @HBatalha `--enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265`

Comment: thanks that works, but how do I build them statically

Comment: @HBatalha I don't know. I don't use Windows. On Super User, and all other Stack Exchange sites, you are expected to only ask 1 question per page. Now you have 4 questions. 1) Difference between ffmpeg versions 2) How to make smaller ffmpeg? 3) What options for mp4, webm, flv, 3gp, avi and audio formats are mp3, m4a, wav, aac, flac, opus? 4) How to make static?

Comment: Oh ok, I think the problem is that I unconsciously take these posts as a conversation where as it goes different questions arise as you're pointed to different directions. But I problem with this, I thanks for pointing it out and make me conscious about it. Thanks too for the tips you gave me.

Comment: Does the essentials build have less features? It could be useful to mention it with the missing features in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller size can mean less available codec and/or formats, depends how a specific ffmpeg version as been compiled
you can check on the different versions the available codec and format with:

```
ffmpeg -codecs
ffmpeg -formats
```

or in windows

```
ffmpeg.exe -codecs
ffmpeg.exe -formats
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! The formats I need are all available in the downgrade version I want to use. As for the codec, I don't know really know much about them, should I be looking for some codec specifically? The video formats I want to use are mp4, webm, flv, 3gp, avi and audio formats are mp3" m4a, wav, aac, flac, opus.

Comment: Could you please provide the version of `FFmpeg` you want to downgrade so it can be checked? (also just a side note, the older version should likely support all those formats, but will use older versions of the encoders which are perhaps slow or more inefficient). If you want a minimalist `FFmpeg` version that *only* has the encoders for the specific formats you want, you may want to consider compiling it yourself, which will result in a smaller program size.

Comment: @pigeonburger "Could you please provide the version of FFmpeg you want to downgrade so it can be checked" - See OP edit